# Use a struct to pronounce multiple variables, giving error

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test
{
    int *a;
    char *s;
}TEST;

int main (void)
{
  TEST A,B;
  A.a[0] = 1;
  A.a[1] = 2;
  A.s = "abc";
  B.a[0] = 1;
  printf("%s\n", A.s);
  printf("%d\n", A.a[0]);
  printf("%d\n", A.a[1]);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile, I received "Segmentation fault".

When I delete the line `B.a[0] = 1;`, it works well. Why?

Comment: Just a clarification about the terms you use, you *don't* get a segmentation fault when you compile, or link. You get it when you run the executable program generated by building (compilation/linking).

Comment: As for your problem, do you know how to use arrays? Do you know how to dynamically allocate memory? And as you declare two pointers as the structure members, where do you think they point if you don't make them point somewhere?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you defined `a` and `c` to be pointers but not arrays?

Comment: @alk Where is `c`?

Comment: @MikeCAT: Oops, `c` should read `s` ... :}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* by using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

You have to allocate some buffer and assign it to `A.a` and `B.a` before using them.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct test
{
    int *a;
    char *s;
}TEST;

int main (void)
{
  TEST A,B;

  /* add these 2 lines to allocate some buffer */
  A.a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
  B.a = malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

  A.a[0] = 1;
  A.a[1] = 2;
  A.s = "abc";
  B.a[0] = 1;
  printf("%s\n", A.s);
  printf("%d\n", A.a[0]);
  printf("%d\n", A.a[1]);

  /* add these 2 lines to free what you allocated */
  free(A.a);
  free(B.a);

  return 0;
}
```

Adding error handling for `malloc()` will make this code better.

Answer (score 1):

The code misses to allocate memory to the pointers `A.a` and `B.a`.

Applying the `[]`-operator to them de-references them (while still pointing "nowhere"), which provokes undefined behaviour. From then on anything might happen.